# How do I initialise a variable in this case?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, p2p

I'm starting an intent where the activity started depends on whether a device is a group owner or just a joined peer. At the moment, instructIntent is not initialised. Am I supposed to make it null as Eclipse suggests? Or is there some more professional, Java code style way of handling this?

```
Intent instructIntent;
if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "DeviceDetailFragment_onCreateView: btn_ready pressed on host");
    instructIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LeaderActivity.class);
} else if (info.groupFormed) {
    Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "DeviceDetailFragment_onCreateView: btn_ready pressed on client");
    instructIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicianActivity.class);
}

instructIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Play");
instructIntent.putExtra(MusicService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS, info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
instructIntent.putExtra(MusicService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8080);
startActivity(instructIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it null won't help.  The real problem is if info.groupFormed is false, you won't have a valid value in instructIntent.  But even if you initialize it to null, it still won't be valid.  That means it will throw an exception when you call putExtra in it.  A better way is to do:

```
if(info.groupFormed){
    if(info.isGroupOwner){
        instructIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LeaderActivity.class);
    }
    else{
        instructIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicianActivity.class);
    }
    //all of your putExtra and startIntent calls here
}
```

Notice that all branches that go to the put and start calls on the intent will create a new intent.  This way you won't have a null or unitnitialized variable trying to call a member function.

Comment: And Intent instructIntent goes after the first if?

Comment: Yes, since it won't be used outside of that if.  Although it won't be a bug to declare it higher up, just a style thing.

Comment: And what if there is no groupFormed at all?

Comment: That's a question you need to answer.  If there is no groupFormed, what do you want it to do?  In your original code it would crash.  In my code, it would do nothing.  If you want it to do something else, add an else to the first if and do it there.

Comment: Spot on answer. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Any variable declared in java should be given value before using it. In the code given above there is possibility that we will not assign any value to the instructIntent variable if both both if and else if condition is not satisfied.

So you have to initialize instructIntent to null as follows.

```
Intent instructIntent = null;
```